# Are there any differences in browser support for <a> link ellement using display: block;

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, cross-browser

I was wondering if there are any differences between the following 3 buttons. And if there are any, how do browsers handle them, including which area is exactly clickable?

On a website I made, I removed all link buttons like the "my-button-1" example and added the class to the A element it self, as with the "my-button-2" example. Using display block. After that I saw a drop in page-views/clicks etc..

Is there any differences for older browsers, when using a link element with display block?

```
<a href="http://example.com">
    <div class="my-button-1">
        Click here
    </div>
</a>

<a href="http://example.com" class="my-button-2">
    Click here
</a>

<div class="my-button">
    <a href="http://example.com">
        Click here
    </a>
</div>

.my-button-1 {
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 50px;
    width: 200px;
}

a.my-button-2 {
    display: block;
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 50px;
    width: 200px;
}

.my-button-3 a {
    display: block;
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 50px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be no difference in older browsers. The display property and block value are and have been fully supported.

In this case, you don't need the inner div and can apply the CSS directly to the a like your 2nd example.

Comment: Thank you, are there any browsers that use default margins/paddings on A elements, so this could interference with the design if you don't set it to zero?

Comment: A is an inline element by default so browsers should not set a default margin / padding,